# Zero Article in Family Names

Tags: zero-article, surnames

This is from an article in a recent issue of *Time* magazine: 
"Barbara Bush has said on several occasions that she suspects Americans are tired of Bushes even as she asserts that Jeb would be the best imaginable President."

Shouldn't it be "*the* Bushes"?
I've never seen a family name pluralized without "the" before.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: This looks like a peeve to me. There's nothing wrong with things like [*"Perhaps voters are tired of Kennedys"*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ryIyAQAAIAAJ&q=%22are+tired+of+Kennedys%22&dq=%22are+tired+of+Kennedys%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VbBaU6CXMsPB7Aafg4CgBA&redir_esc=y)

Comment: My intuition is that _Americans are tired of the Bushes_ means "Americans are tired of the Bush family as a collective", while _Americans are tired of Bushes_ means "Americans are tired of individual people bearing the name 'Bush'".

Comment: @senshin Yes; I think Barbara Bush is sensibly using the hedged, distancing version ('Bushes') rather than the nearer-to-home (though as OP suggests rather more accurate) version ('the Bushes' – or worse, 'us Bushes').

Comment: Thank you very much senshin, I think I got my answer from you :-)

Comment: You could say both versions were 'hedged'...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Family names can be accompanied either by the definite article *the* ("the Smiths") or by the zero article ("Smiths"). However, these two constructions mean slightly different things.

> Americans are tired of *the Bushes*.

This construction suggests that Americans are tired of "the Bushes" as a collective entity - that is, Americans are tired of the whole goshdarned Bush family, taken as a single group.

> Americans are tired of *Bushes*.

This construction, [as Edwin Ashworth eloquently points out](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/166242/zero-article-in-family-names#comment345853_166242), is "hedged" and "distancing" - it suggests that Americans are tired of various "Bushes", each taken individually, without requiring the speaker (a Bush) to assert that Americans are tired of a group that includes her.

That is, Americans might be tired of George H. W. Bush, and also tired of George W. Bush, and also tired of Jeb Bush, and maybe even tired of Prescott Bush - but Americans are not necessarily tired of Bushes as a whole; just some Bushes in particular.